# Check if button has been clicked within time

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, conditional-statements

This is what I'd like to do:

1. User clicks on button, Run **Function A**
2. If button **hasn't** been clicked again within 1 second, Run **Function B** too
3. If button **has** been clicked, **repeat** (run function A again and check for function B)

This is what I've tried

```
var clicked = false;

$('#button').click(function(){
    A();
}); 

function A(){
    clicked = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
         clicked == false;
    )}, 1000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        if ( clicked == false ) {
            B();
        }
    )}, 1000);
}
```

I think the code will for scenario **1** and **2**, but how can I get it working for **3** too?

**EDIT:** Just saw a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081359/check-if-a-button-hasnt-been-clicked-within-a-certain-amount-of-time-jquery?rq=1) upon posting which I didn't find through search. Please wait while I check if it's a duplicate

Comment: Are you just trying to prevent double clicks?

Comment: What do you mean by 'repeat scenario 1' ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prevent function B from running when the user spam clicks. Function A should allow that though.

Comment: Repeat nr 1 in the list.

Comment: Are you ultimately trying to prevent `B()` from running more than once every second? If so, shouldn't the first call to `A()` also invoke `B()`, but then prevent it for a second? Your question isn't clear on that.

Comment: Isn't it enough http://jsfiddle.net/Zvbxv/1 ???

Comment: @cookiemonster that's correct

Comment: @TonyFire the revised answer should do the trick. note that it doesn't suffice to record the click with a boolean, otherwise two clicks at t=0, t=0.5 will both be cleared by the reset operation at t=1.

Comment: I'll try it out. However, A. Wolff solution worked and looks simpler.

Comment: The author is Juan Mendes. Basically it's the same idea streamlined.

Comment: @collapsar I'm the author of my own comment ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff oh, sorry, didn't get that one, I thought that Tony talks about the solution you edited ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to throttle (buffer) the clicks, that is, you want to wait a specified amount of time before you act, if the same event happens again within your throttling period, you restart your wait. http://jsfiddle.net/8QdLV/

```
function B() {
    console.log('Clicked')
}
var timeoutId;
$('#button').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeOutId = setTimeout(B, 1000);
});
```

This can be generalized http://jsfiddle.net/8QdLV/

```
function throttle(handler, buffer) {
    var timeoutId;
    buffer = buffer || 1000;
    return function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        var me = this;
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            handler.call(me, e);
        }, buffer);
    }
}

$('button').click(throttle(function() {
    console.log('Throttled click');
});
```

By the way, you may want to use https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/ which also provides a `$.throttle` function

Comment: Why restart? This will perpetually delay the invocation of `B` as long as the user keeps clicking. Probably not what he wants to do.

Comment: @cookiemonster That's an option, the OP is free to change the code not to restart it. However, I think the OP does want to wait until they are not being click spammed for a second before they execute the handler.

Comment: Could be. Just that if you do it that way on the first click, the user may be wondering why nothing is happening, and keep clicking without intending to spam. I think at least the first click needs to be allowed. Otherwise it's just a bad user experience.

Comment: @cookiemonster To me, the bad use experience is that if they spam click the  button 3 times; at times 0ms, 500ms, and 1100ms, the handler would get called twice, which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: ...nevermind, he clarified in a comment that even the initial click should be delayed.

Comment: @cookiemonster The most common use of throttling is being notified that the user has stopped typing (in autocomplete fields), so you throttle the keypress events for, say 500ms before you send an AJAX request to get the autocomplete results. In this case, you definitely want to wait until the user stops typing.

Answer (score 0):

use the `setInterval` function.

note that it doesn't suffice to record the click with a boolean, otherwise two clicks at `t=0`, `t=0.99` will both be cleared by the reset operation at `t=1`.

```
var clicked = false
  , hnd_reset = null
  , hnd_check = null;

$('#button').click(function() {
    A();
}); 

function A(){
    clicked = true;
    hnd_reset = setTimeout(function(){
         clicked = false;
         hnd_reset = null;
    )}, 1000);

    if (hnd_check === null) {
        hnd_check = setInterval(function(){
            if ( !clicked && (hnd_reset === null)) {
                clearInterval( hnd_check );
                hnd_check = null;
                B();
            }
        )}, 1000);
    }
}
```

alternatively you could track the number of clicks in an int starting at 0, allowing for execution of `B` iff the tracker is 0.